# spring boot 3 native fail with javaAgent configured

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I must say that I am pretty new with graalvm (like most people nowadays).
I have been following [this guide](https://github.com/spring-tips/spring-boot-3-aot) created by [@joshLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607357/josh-long) to create a spring boot native application.
In the guide it explains that we can use the java agent while executing tests in order to create the `reflect-config.json` and other files that are "given as an input to the graalVm compiler". This is also explained in the spring boot documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#native-image.advanced.using-the-tracing-agent) and also [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#native-image.advanced.using-the-tracing-agent.launch)

I created a repo (Which is a clone of the one from the guide), and just made one commit in order to "activate the java agent while executing the test" (in the history of the branch just look at the last commit).

please get it like this:
`git clone https://github.com/clembo590/issues.git --branch issue_with_agent`

when executing: `mvn clean -P native native:compile` I get this error

```
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: New Method or Constructor found as reachable after static analysis: public java.lang.String com.example.aot.properties.DemoProperties.name()
```

I looked on the web if I could find something about this issue:
I found [one issue on github about that](https://github.com/oracle/graal/discussions/4670) , but I do not know how to fix it in the case of a spring boot app.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I compiled the code in my local did not get that error check https://gist.github.com/ozkanpakdil/814d0e25baecb84cc5513885f6af113d

Comment: thanks a lot! This was actually fixed by the last release of graalvm (it was not working with graalvm64-17.0.5 but WORKS with graalvm64-17.0.6)